# Can't create a bootable USB/DVD for Clear linux

Tags: virtualbox, tar, bootable, clear-linux

I am currently using windows and would like to create a VB instance of Clear linux.

But when I download the installer or the live img.xz file as instructed here https://clearlinux.org/documentation/clear-linux/get-started/bare-metal-install

I am able to extract it using ubuntu bash within windows (or winzip/winrar/poweriso.exe within windows) but when I burn a bootable DVD or USB using imgburn/poweriso/Win32DiskImager/Rufus I always end up with an unreadable USB or DVD.

The USB has no label or GB enumeration and when clicking on it to open through explorer windows prompts me to format it

And the DVDs always end up being unlabeled as well and of 0 bytes

I tried to redownload the img.xz files and burned it numerous times to different DVDs and USBs using a variety of programs but I had 0 success the end result was always the same (while the extraction and/or burning/creation of the bootable USB/DVD always was a success according to imgburn or whatever esle I have used)

Also VB cant read it as a source to install linux... I cant even select it(usb or DVD)

What am I doing wrong?

My DVD burner or USB sticks are functional if I try to burn lets say a ubuntu image everything works fine...

Is there anything  special going on with .img files? since I could not find an .iso file of clear linux but only .img files (compressed in tar)

Comment: Have you checked the MD5 checksum value of your downloaded *.IMG file yet, papajo?

Comment: No because I do not know whith what value to compare it with ...  But I doubt its the resource file since I downloaded directly from the main server and downloaded multiple instances (also I have a clear fast internet connection with no disconnects or variable speed etc)  I think that the issue is that they dont provide an ISO file and on windows the img file has compatibility issues? something like that

Comment: No, on Windows *.IMG files do not have any compatibility issues, but your CD/DVD burning software could have various issues. Try *Padus Disc Juggler* Or *Glorylogic ISO Workshop* whatever you use, DO NOT SET HIGHEST RECORDING SPEED, LET BURNING COMPLETE WHEN IT DOES.

Comment: I am not a noob (in general) I am 100% sure the recording as a process was 100% successful each time (And yes I also tried to burn at a slower speed + I tried USB creation) but as far as the software goes I really don't know if it has issues (its the most popular though especially rufus and imgburn) anyway I will try the software you mentioned as well.. it really bugs me that they dont have .iso files though...  thank you.

Comment: @Fido-X Disk Juggler does not even support .img files to begin with and Glorylogic ISO workshop is broken/buggy... It has a nice feature that allows to convert an image file of X format to iso format but either its isoCD or its buggy since when I try to convert the img file the process doesnt even start but returns an error immediately "no sense information found" and as far as I googled that error is relevant to disc burning problems (e.g the medium you try to burn is smaller in size than the source) but I don burn any disk I just had set a directory to where the iso file should be created.

Comment: @Fido-X +the ISO workshop cant burn my disks at all for some reason (error:1) and I have no issue with burning my disks from nero workshop to whatever else I tried to run as a burning program (and I tried a lot) this also lead me to believe that ISO workshop is kinda buggy...

Comment: That's ridiculous! Which version of Windows do you have? How much space on partition where CD/DVD tools  should be storing thiir temp image? Download Deamon Tools, mount that *.img file and try to convert it to *.iso image file.

Comment: That might just be reason why all of your CD/DVDs are coasters, it's something with your hardware. Hardware Info?

Comment: I'm now in Linux so i'm unable to access any of those tools (i have both Disc Juggler and ISO WORKSHOP).

Comment: Just thought of something. Google to find whether all virtual boxes support *.img files find the one which does, then install that and try your *.img image in there.

Comment: The most ridiculous part imho is that people @ clear linux do not provide .iso images.  As for my windows version its 10/64bit I have both a LG BR recorder (expensive one) and an Expensive pioneer DVD recorder which have no issues what so ever and used different sorts of blank disks. I am 100% sure that my hardware is OK (besides that the same problem appears when I try to make a bootable **USB** stick using those .img files so its not a speed/burning/disc related issue for sure its those files that clear linux provides or those files in relation with windows/drivers/standards )

Comment: Ok downloaded Daemon tools... it can mount the image but same thing happens as with the disks I burned... windows can not open them.

Comment: Since you're so sure your hardware is ok... let's make sure *.img files are also ok. But first one more try, this time using Win32DiskImager on **my way of doing things, ok?**

Comment: You don't really need to copy the file to USB. Virtualbox can convert from raw img.  https://clearlinux.org/documentation/clear-linux/get-started/virtual-machine-install/virtualbox

Comment: [*Intel’s Clear Linux is not your everyday Linux distribution*](https://itsfoss.com/clear-linux/) and it's definitely not for beginners, like [Kali Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/399626/44425). If you're not familiar with Linux in general you should use Ubuntu or the like first. `No because I do not know whith what value to compare it with` Intel already explains clearly how to check the SHA1 sum for image integrity in their installation help page. And if you're ending up with a "unreadable" USB in Windows then there's absolutely no problem with that, Windows can't read ext4 partition

Comment: flashing the image file in dd mode like other Linux distributions won't give you a usable normal USB flash drive because the MBR has been destroyed. You need to open disk management and remove all the partitions then create a new NTFS/FAT32 partition again. `it can mount the image but same thing happens as with the disks I burned... windows can not open them` why on earth you always try to open a Linux disk image in Windows? Just reboot and select the USB drive for startup

Answer (score 0):

Download **AOMEI partition Assistant Standard Edition**, install it, use it to completely ERASE your potentially corrupt USB (not just format it, ERASE it) then create a new filesystem according to your USB drive size (probably it will be FAT 32).

Then use Win32DiskImager to burn that *.img file to USB and in BIOS under BOOT DEVICE PRIORITY select USB-HDD as your 1st boot device (your BIOS could have those options with different names).

That should work.

Comment: I mentioned that I did that, and that doesn't work the USB ends up being unreadable. 

If someone could just convert the img file found on their website ( https://download.clearlinux.org/image/clear-20860-installer.img.xz ) to an .iso format and give me a link to download it I would be very grateful since I am 100% sure there is something going on related to drivers/formats/standards and those .img files are only "readable" in a linux environment.

Comment: @papajo, you haven't mentioned anything about using**AOMEI Partition Assistant Standard Edition** nor **ERASING USB AFTER IT WAS UNREADABLE AND BEFORE TRYING AGAIN**.  You have mentioned: "The USB has no label or GB enumeration and when clicking on it to open through explorer windows prompts me to format it... And the DVDs always end up being unlabeled as well and of 0 bytes..."

Comment: Trying to burn *.img/*.iso files to a corrupt USB is never a good idea unless USB has been erased before new attempt, i know what i went through with UNETBootin and some weird *.iso images a few years ago... Also you should contact those who brought that *.img image there, the owners, authors about that - it's not normal for *.img files to be like that. And if there's no contact information, it must be some scam or something malicious. We're not authors of that image so we can't help you.

Comment: I did not mention that bogus AOEMEI shareware software because Ive done it (to erase the partition and create a new one) the **the proper way** through diskpart and other windows default software.  Also the USB drive**S** (yes a plural) are new and I also tried disk**S** ... You essentially are saying that the reason why I cant use the file is because either I am totally computer illiterate or because everything I own in terms of hardware is corrupted or broken... Which I dont appreciate.

Comment: That's not what i really meant, but from what i have read (all DVDs are zero bytes, coasters; all USB drives lost their filesystems) it easily leads people to think that you're either computer illiterate or have bad hardware or bad *.img image or a combo of all that. You see that this conversation is between you and me only... ...and for everything i have suggested you seem to have some *your way* of doing (Windows default software, DISKPART). I can suggest some more things because i really, really want to see that your troubles are solved. But you have to follow my instructions.

Comment: Try to get to some Linux terminal and then: `fdisk -l` to find your USB,   `dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sdX` where X is the letter of your USB drive. After that use `dd bs=512M if=your_image.img of=/dev/sdX` where X is replaced with letter of your USB drive. And if this doesn't work, Google to find some software which can convert **.img files to ISO and then try to write it to USB with dd method.

Comment: Note: `dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sdX` will erase /dev/sdX with random data.

Comment: the USB is not corrupted. It's just appeared as *unformatted* in Windows because Windows doesn't understand ext4 partitions. This happens with all Linux install disk when writing in dd mode